# Understanding Chart from Google SRE Book

Tags: monitoring, http

While reading [Site Reliability Engineering](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920041528.do), I read the following:

[image]

I don't understand how to read this chart. As I understand the purple region represents the 50th percentile (half of all traffic).

And, the time it takes, for the 50th percentile, for the HTTP request to be carried out, i.e. receive an HTTP response, can be taken from y=0 ms to y=~60ms?

If that's right, then:

- what's the meaning of 99th percentile?
- how can I figure out the response time for the top blue area, i.e. 99th? Do I measure from y=0 ms or y=1k ms?

Answer (score 4):

If the number of formula's in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) article scares you off:

> what's the meaning of 99th percentile?

The cut-off point which fits 99% of the observed values. For instance when the 99<sup>th</sup> percentile is 3000 milliseconds => 99% of all observed latencies are 3000 milliseconds or less. Or in other words: only 1% of observed latencies is larger than 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks - that helps. Could you please take a look at my second question - how to figure out latency, i.e. time to handle http request, of the blue area?

Comment: The *"blue **area**"* is the 4% percent of requests between 99th percentile and the 95th percentile. Where 95 percent of requests have a latency of roughly 1000 milliseconds or less, and 99 percent of requests usually have a latency of 5 seconds or less.